# "Assert in junit.framework has been deprecated" - what next to use?

Tags: junit, junit4

I bump version of `junit` to 4.11 and get:

```
[WARNING] [deprecation] Assert in junit.framework has been deprecated
[WARNING] [deprecation] Assert in junit.framework has been deprecated
....
```

How and to what migrate?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

As it seems the Assert class has been moved from `junit.framework` to `org.junit.Assert` in JUnit 4.0 - you can use that instead, it's not deprecated.

Comment: How would I go about telling eclipse never to use the deprecated `junit.framework` ever again?

Comment: To atrioom: Window » Preferences » Java » Appearence » Type Filters, then add junit.framework.Assert.*

Comment: @atrioom: I think you can also add `java.awt.List` while your at it :P

Answer (score 86):

Change your import statement from

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
```

to

```
import org.junit.Assert;
```

and this will rectify your JUnit deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 19):

Both are depricated:

```
junit.framework.Assert.assertThat
org.junit.Assert.assertThat
```

**According to docs, use Instead:**

```
org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat
```

Comment: But `hamcrest` is a separate project (and throws another exception to indicate failures). Can you clarify what is the purpose of https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html is JUnit 5?

Answer (score 5):

After facing this problem I have tried lots of ways to solve this but failed again and again.

The good thing is: I have download `junit-4.12.jar` file from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/junit/junit/4.12/source-code) and added the jar file in the project section under the `libs` folder. If previously any kind of Junit dependancy exist in the project then remove that from the `build.gradle` and `build` + `clean` your project.

It is worked for me. Hope it will work for you.

**Note: Take a look in the image that I attached in below.**

Thank you

[image]

Comment: This solution worked for me, i just removed the dependency f`androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'` from the `build.gradle(App level)` and place the `junit-4.12.jar` in the `app\libs` directory and `build` the project, thanks man, you saved me

Answer (score 2):

We had a large number of tests with many assertions.

Adding something like

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
```

to the import statements also helped to limit the changes in test code.

Answer (score 1):

According to [JUnit5 Doc.](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips) assertions in JUnit 5 are moved to `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions`.

For example,

JUnit 4 `import org.junit.Assert`

becomes

`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions` in JUnit 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to jUnit4 Assert class methods from [JUnit4](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/Assert.html)